# How can I move to left (hide) a <div> with JQuery when load a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like hide a `<div>` to user but he/she can't see the process for hidden and the other pages elements use the this div space.

My page:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
        <ul class="sidebar-nav">
            <li>
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div> content...</div>
</div>
```

I searched for all sites but I two ways different to I like.

1. hide div but the div space is static and another html objects don't use this space.

   ```
   $('#sidebar-wrapper').toggle();
   ```
2. hide div but user sees the process.

   ```
   $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
   ```

Thank you!

Comment: Hide them by default and instead use jQuery to show them for users who are supposed to see the elements.

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to accomplish. Do you ever plan on showing the `div`? What are you asking us to help with?

Comment: as @APAD1 has mentioned, just have it hidden by default and add functionality to display the div. no point in having it show just to immediately disappear when the page loads

Comment: Yes, I have another code for manage the div visualization, but I would like user don't see this to load the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for all.

This is my solution:

```
var tamAnterior = $(window).width();
var tamActual = tamAnterior;
$(window).resize(function(){
    tamActual = $(this).width();
    if((tamAnterior < 767 && tamActual >= 767) || (tamActual < 767 && tamAnterior >= 767)){
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
    }
    tamAnterior = $(this).width();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to hide menu somewhere out of screen boundaries (in left) and when site is downloaded totally to show up?

Check this:

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  $('#sidebar-wrapper').animate({
    'left': 0
  }, 300);
});
```

```css
#sidebar-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  left: -100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
        <ul class="sidebar-nav">
            <li>
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div> content...</div>
</div>
```